# How to display additional content on website when screen resolution is bigger than normal?

Tags: web, resolution

Hy guys.I wanted to ask u is there any code that will help me creating content when screen resolution is bigger.I am talking about web sites.
I have two pictures which are showing what i want to say

1. This pictures shows how web page looks when screen (monitor) resolution is normal:

[link of first image] http://prntscr.com/3ghd1n

1. Second picture shows how web page should looks like when screen resolution is bigger than normal.There are new few new "div-s" that appears.

[link of second image] http://prntscr.com/3ghdst

Comment: Have you considered media queries? set display:none in @media(screenwidth < 980px) etc.?

Comment: No, i have no ideas that could help me, so i was hopping someone have something that could "push" me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should take a look at is CSS3 Media Queries. There are other programmatic approaches using script but MQ is just really easy.

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Here is a good starting point. You're search phrase would be 'Media Queries' for other research in Google. Essentially a media query allows you to specify styles, such as 'display' depending on screen size. You can simply show or hide, or move things around depending on whether the client has a large resolution or a very small one.

Comment: Thank u, that was thing i was looking for :)